# Tomcat stops after restarting it from jenkins execution shell

Tags: java, linux, shell, tomcat, jenkins

I have configured jenkins to deleted tomcat existing workspace, copy the existing build to tomcat workspace and then restart tomcat. I use execute shell from jenkins. The script is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
version=1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
build_no=${BUILD_NUMBER}

if [ $build_no ]
then
 cd ~
 TOMCAT_WEBAPPS=`locate apache-tomcat | grep apache-tomcat | grep webapps | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $1 }'`
 rm $TOMCAT_WEBAPPS/app-api.war
 rm -rf $TOMCAT_WEBAPPS/app-api/*
 rmdir $TOMCAT_WEBAPPS/app-api/
 wget http://jenkins/job/project/ws/api/build/api-$version-$build_no-bin.zip
 unzip -j connectedcare-api-$version-$build_no-bin.zip
 rm api-$version-$build_no-bin.zip
 cp api-$version.war $TOMCAT_WEBAPPS/app-api.war
 rm api-$version.war
else
 echo "Please specify the jenkins build number as an argument: "$0" <build_number>"
 exit
fi

echo "Restarting tomcat ..."

TOMCAT_PID=`ps -ef | grep tomcat | grep java | awk ' { print $2 } '`

if [ $TOMCAT_PID ]
then
  echo "Tomcat is running with PID" $TOMCAT_PID

  echo "Forced tomcat stop with PID" $TOMCAT_PID
  kill -9 $TOMCAT_PID
  echo "Tomcat was stoped"
fi

echo "Starting tomcat"

TOMCAT_STARTUP_FILE=`locate apache-tomcat | grep apache-tomcat | grep startup.sh | awk ' { print $1 } '`

$TOMCAT_STARTUP_FILE

TOMCAT_PID=`ps -ef | grep tomcat | grep java | awk ' { print $2 } '`

if [ $TOMCAT_PID ]
then
  echo "Tomcat is running with PID" $TOMCAT_PID
else
  echo "Failed to start tomcat."
fi
```

When running the build, the result is as follows:

```
Restarting tomcat ...
Tomcat PID 10152
Tomcat is running with PID 10152
Forced tomcat stop with PID 10152
Tomcat was stoped
Starting tomcat
Tomcat started.
Tomcat is running with PID 14781
```

The problem is then when I am looking at the linux machine tomcat is no running, and the is nothing in the logs, so I can't figure it out what I am doing wrong. Can you please give me some suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a solution for this. Jenkins manipulate the environment variable called BUILD_ID. so before restarting tomcat the following line of code is needed.

export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe